# Как вывести описание (summary) к gridview в yii2, вне грида

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, виджет

Есть GridView, можно ли както вывести описание (summary) (1-10, из 24), например, вне этого грида, в отдельный блок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (($pagination = $dataProvider->pagination) && ($count = $dataProvider->getCount())) {
    $totalCount = $dataProvider->getTotalCount();
    $begin = $pagination->getPage() * $pagination->pageSize + 1;
    $end = $begin + $count - 1;
    if ($begin > $end) {
        $begin = $end;
    }
    echo "<p>Showing <b>{$begin}-{$end}</b> of <b>{$totalCount}</b>.</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызываем еще раз виджет и просто указываем нужный лайаут.
'layout' => '{summary}'